# The Mazur–Ulam Theorem: A generalization to arbitrary topological vector spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces

Is there a corresponding result for arbitrary topological vector spaces? For example, is a surjective isometry between linear metric spaces affine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a positive result of Rolewicz for locally bounded F-spaces:

> S. Rolewicz, [A generalization of the Mazur–Ulam theorem](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/sm/sm31/sm3157.pdf), *Studia Math.*, **31** (1968), 501–505.

There is an extension of this result due to W. Jian:

> W. Jian, [On the Generalizations of the Mazur–Ulam Isometric Theorem](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022247X01976279), *Journal of Mathematical Analysis and Applications*, **263** (2001), 510–521.

I believe that for general metric linear spaces the problem remains open.